# Haskell Function composition of two binary functions?

Tags: haskell, monads, function-composition

I'm working my way through [20 Intermediate Haskell exercises](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/DanBurton/20-intermediate-exercises) and I got stuck on exercise 13:

```
-- Exercise 13
-- Relative Difficulty: 6
apple :: (Misty m) => m a -> m (a -> b) -> m b
apple = error "todo"
```

where the Misty Typeclass is essentially the Monad Typeclass and is implemented like this:

```
class Misty m where
    banana :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
    unicorn :: a -> m a
```

I gave in to my curiosity and found the solution to this exercise online as

```
apple = banana . flip furry'
```

where furry' is a version of liftM implemented as

```
furry' f mi = banana (\x -> unicorn (f x)) mi
```

What I don't understand is the use of function composition (.) on two binary functions (namely banana and the flipped furry'), if someone could walk through the evaluation of this I think that would help me a lot.

Comment: Now that I get to read these typeclasses with names like `misty`, `furry` and `banana` I understand why so many people dislike their mathematical names...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start step by step. `Misty` typeclass is given:

```
class Misty m where 
  banana :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b 
  unicorn :: a -> m a
```

Also `furry'` is already solved in an earlier problem in those exercises:

```
furry' :: Misty m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
furry' f mi = banana (\x -> unicorn (f x)) mi
```

Now you have `apple` function which you have to define:

```
apple :: (Misty m) => m a -> m (a -> b) -> m b
apple = error "todo"
```

Now just try to follow the type signature. Assume you are defining `apple` like this:

```
apple xs ys

xs will have type of m a

ys will have type of m (a -> b)
```

Now can you see the relation between the above types and `furry'` ? So
you have to somehow apply `xs` and `ys` to `furry'` Now since it's
second parameter is `m a` which you already have in `xs`, you can use
`flip` to obtain it:

`flip furry' ::  m a -> (a -> b) -> m b`

So you can apply `xs` to the first parameter of it and you will have
the following type signature:

`(flip furry') xs :: (a -> b) -> m b`   **-------** **Equation** **1**

Any guess on how to apply it `ys`? Try to unify the above type
signature with the first parameter of `banana` :

That will give you:

```
a ~ (a -> b)
m b ~ (m b)
```

So, the type signature of `banana` gets transformed from

```
banana :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

to

```
banana :: ((a -> b) -> m b) -> m (a -> b) -> m b
```

Now from `Equation (1)` we know that `(flip furry') xs` type signature matches
the first parameter of `banana` and `ys` matches the second parameter
of `banana`. And that gives you the definition of `apple`:

```
apple :: (Misty m) => m a -> m (a -> b) -> m b
apple xs ys = banana ((flip furry') xs ) ys
```

which can be expressed in pointfree manner as:

```
apple :: (Misty m) => m a -> m (a -> b) -> m b
apple = banana . flip furry'
```